# Where did Cecianiah Corabelle come from?

Tags: code-geass

The actual name of C.C. or C2 has been a topic on the net because no one besides the author knows it. But for some reason the names "Elizabeth" and "Cecaniah Corabelle" pops up. Now the question is, why Cecaniah Corabelle?

I can understand why "Elizabeth" might be suggested; it was a common name at the time and place in Europe where C.C lived.

But "Cecaniah" is a rather unusual name and I couldn't find it anywhere. So why would she be named Cecaniah Corabelle? Is there anything suggesting such a name? 
Where did this theory begin?

Comment: Cecania and variations of it is a German female name meaning free/freedom. Cora is of Greek origin meaning maiden, variations of it are Corabella, Corabelle, Corri, etc. There are no sources to corroborate claims of any official name for CC other than her initials.

Comment: Is this form the manga?

Answer (score -3):

I believe her first name is white: Cilla 
and 2nd name is snow:
Chan,
Chilali,
Chilam,

The reason I believe so is episode 11 when he says her name 3 times then Kallen comes and he says: "Snow is white white snow is pretty". You hear 2 drops of water  and her famous quote  talks about snow and white.  So my conclusion is her name should have white, snow, pretty (snow  white) (white snow)

And I believe it's white snow because I don't think the author will name her snow white.

Comment: i don't believe Kallen shows up while they were in the cave and Lelouch's talk about Snow was after he and C.C left, an after comment to C.C's comment about asking if he knew why Snow was white (after Lelouch Geass the JLF Watchman) saying because it's forgotten it's name, like she has. Lelouch's after comment was that despite this Snow is still beautiful (by extension saying C.C is beautiful)